# How to use deep learning models for time-series forecasting?

Tags: python, deep-learning, time-series, lstm, forecasting

I have signals recorded from machines `(m1, m2, so on)` for 28 days. (Note: each signal in each day is 360 length long).

```
machine_num, day1, day2, ..., day28
m1, [12, 10, 5, 6, ...], [78, 85, 32, 12, ...], ..., [12, 12, 12, 12, ...]
m2, [2, 0, 5, 6, ...], [8, 5, 32, 12, ...], ..., [1, 1, 12, 12, ...]
...
m2000, [1, 1, 5, 6, ...], [79, 86, 3, 1, ...], ..., [1, 1, 12, 12, ...]
```

I want to predict the signal sequence of each machine for next 3 days. i.e. in `day29`, `day30`, `day31`.
However, I  don't have values for days `29`, `30` and `31`. So, my plan was as follows using `LSTM` model.

The first step is to get signals for `day 1` and asked to predict signals for `day 2`, then in the next step get signals for `days 1, 2` and asked to predict signals for `day 3`, etc, so when I reach `day 28,` the network has all the signals up to 28 and is asked to predict the signals for `day 29`, etc.

I tried to do a univariant LSTM model as follows.

```
# univariate lstm example
from numpy import array
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dense
# define dataset
X = array([[10, 20, 30], [20, 30, 40], [30, 40, 50], [40, 50, 60]])
y = array([40, 50, 60, 70])
# reshape from [samples, timesteps] into [samples, timesteps, features]
X = X.reshape((X.shape[0], X.shape[1], 1))
# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, activation='relu', input_shape=(3, 1)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
# fit model
model.fit(X, y, epochs=1000, verbose=0)
# demonstrate prediction
x_input = array([50, 60, 70])
x_input = x_input.reshape((1, 3, 1))
yhat = model.predict(x_input, verbose=0)
print(yhat)
```

However, this example is very simple since it does not have long sequences like mine. For example, my data for `m1` would look as follows.

```
m1 = [[12, 10, 5, 6, ...], [78, 85, 32, 12, ...], ..., [12, 12, 12, 12, ...]]
```

Moreover, I need the prediction of day `29`, `30`, `31`. In that case, I am unsure how to change this example to cater my needs. I want to sepcifically know if the direction I have chosen is correct. If so, how to do it.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

## EDIT:

I have mentioned the `model.summary()`.

[image]

Comment: Maybe this answer has it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46901371/how-to-deal-with-multi-step-time-series-forecasting-in-multivariate-lstm-in-kera/46934799#46934799 --- Later I may write a specific answer to your question, with time.

Comment: @DanielMöller Thank you very much for the comment. Sure, I will look at the answer of that question. Please kindly post an answer for this question as well when you get a free time. Looking forward to hearing from you. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @DanielMöller I am very curios to know your suggestions on this question. That is why I thought to quickly check if you would get some time to post an answer. It would be a great help for me. Thank you very much. Looking forward to hearing from you :)

Comment: Commenting because I can't save this link right now and very interested in the topic.

Comment: @CeliusStingher Thank you very much for the comment. It is really great to hear that you are interested in the topic. Please kindly let me know your suggestions. I look forward to hearing from you. Thank you :)

Comment: @CeliusStingher Hi, this is just to check whether you have suggestions on this question. If so, please kindly let me know them. Thank you :)

Comment: Thank you for the reminder. Just to make sure I understand the dimensions correctly, we have 2000 machines that record an array for 360 values for each day. So all arrays are the same dimension and we could say the matrix is 2000*28*360 right?

Comment: @CeliusStingher Thank you very much for the comment. Yes, you are correct. I have data of 2000 machines on 28 days. For each day I have an array of 360. Therefore the matrix is 2000*28*360. Please let me know if you need any further details. Looking forward for your suggestions. Thank you :)

Comment: Final question before testing, what is the relation between the 360 observations and each day. Can we say each observation is independent from the other (for each day) and what about observation 1 for day 1 and observation 1 for day 2? Could we find relationship between these values? Kind of like a MANOVA... TL;DR: Are there any relations that should be taken into account between the values?

Comment: @CeliusStingher Thank you very much for the comment. Sorry for the delayed response as I saw your comment just now. The 360 observations for each day are calculated as follows. From every machine I collected its signal for every minute in 6 hours. i.e. the length of the signal of a machine is 6*60 = 360. Each machine has 360 length signals for 28 days. I have the data of about 2000 machines in my dataset. Unfortunately, I have not done MANOVA for the dataset. Please kindly let me know if my description is not clear. Thank you. Looking forward to hearing from you :)

Comment: @CeliusStingher Hi, please let me know if you need any further details. Looking forward for your suggestions. Thank you :)

Comment: I probably wont be able to get into it until saturday. Ibelieve I've got everything I need for now :)

Comment: @CeliusStingher Thank you very much for the comment. Sure, I look forward to hearing from you on Saturday. Thank you :)

Comment: @DanielMöller Hi, I know you will have great suggestions on this question. Please let me know your thoughts if you get a free time. Thank you very much :)

Comment: So.... are they "sequences within sequences"? The 360 are sequentially displayed, minute by minute, right? The 360 measures are a sequence.... --- Then you have the day sequence that you want to forecast....

Comment: Last question.... are these machines "of the same nature"? Can we treat each machine as a similar individual, supposing that if machine 1 measured X for 28 days, and machine 2 also measured X for 28 days, the forecast for machine 1 and machine 2 should be the same?

Comment: @DanielMöller Thank you very much for the comments. Yes you are correct. From every machine I collected its signal for every minute in 6 hours. i.e. the length of the signal of a machine is 6*60 = 360. Yes, you are correct with respect to your second comment.  If machine 1 measured X for 28 days, and machine 2 also measured X for 28 days, the forecast for machine 1 and machine 2 should be the same. Please kindly let me know if you need further details. Looking forward to hearing from you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Model and shapes

Since these are sequences in sequences, you need to use your data in a different format.

Although you could just go like `(machines, days, 360)` and simply treat the 360 as features (that could work up to some point), for a robust model (then maybe there is a speed problem) you'd need to treat both things as sequences.

Then I'd go with data like `(machines, days, 360, 1)` and two levels of recurrency.

Our models `input_shape` then would be `(None, 360, 1)`

#### Model case 1 - Only day recurrency

Data shape: `(machines, days, 360)`
Apply some normalization to the data.

Here, an example, but models can be flexible as you can add more layers, try convolutions, etc:

```
inputs = Input((None, 360)) #(m, d, 360)
outs = LSTM(some_units, return_sequences=False, 
            stateful=depends_on_training_approach)(inputs)  #(m, some_units)
outs = Dense(360, activation=depends_on_your_normalization)(outs) #(m, 360)
outs = Reshape((1,360)) #(m, 1, 360) 
    #this reshape is not necessary if using the "shifted" approach - see time windows below
    #it would then be (m, d, 360)

model = Model(inputs, outs)
```

Depending on the complexity of the intra-daily sequences, they could get well predicted with this, but if they evolve in a complex way, then the next model would be a little better.

Always remember that you can create more layers and explore things to increase the capability of this model, this is only a tiny example

#### Model case 2 - Two level recurrency

Data shape:  `(machines, days, 360, 1)`
Apply some normalization to the data.

There are so many many ways to experiment on how to do this, but here is a simple one.

```
inputs = Input((None, 360, 1)) #(m, d, 360, 1)

#branch 1
inner_average = TimeDistributed(
                    Bidirectional(
                        LSTM(units1, return_sequences=True, stateful=False),
                        merge_mode='ave'
                    )
                )(inputs) #(m, d, 360, units1)
inner_average = Lambda(lambda x: K.mean(x, axis=1))(inner_average) #(m, 360, units1)


#branch 2
inner_seq = TimeDistributed(
                LSTM(some_units, return_sequences=False, stateful=False)
            )(inputs) #may be Bidirectional too
            #shape (m, d, some_units)

outer_seq = LSTM(other_units, return_sequences = False, 
                 stateful=depends_on_training_approach)(inner_seq) #(m, other_units)

outer_seq = Dense(few_units * 360, activation = 'tanh')(outer_seq) #(m, few_units * 360)
    #activation = same as inner_average 


outer_seq = Reshape((360,few_units))(outer_seq) #(m, 360, few_units)


#join branches

outputs = Concatenate()([inner_average, outer_seq]) #(m, 360, units1+few_units)
outputs = LSTM(units, return_sequences=True, stateful= False)(outputs) #(m, 360,units)
outputs = Dense(1, activation=depends_on_your_normalization)(outputs) #(m, 360, 1)
outputs = Reshape((1,360))(outputs) #(m, 1, 360) for training purposes

model = Model(inputs, outputs)
```

This is one attempt, I made an average of the days, but I could have made, instead of `inner_average`, something like:

```
#branch 1
daily_minutes = Permute((2,1,3))(inputs) #(m, 360, d, 1)
daily_minutes = TimeDistributed(
                    LSTM(units1, return_sequences=False, 
                         stateful=depends_on_training_approach)
                )(daily_minutes) #(m, 360, units1)
```

Many other ways of exploring the data are possible, this is a highly creative field. You could, for instance, use the `daily_minutes` approach right after the `inner_average` excluding the `K.mean` lambda layer.... you got the idea.

## Time windows approach

Your approach sounds nice. Give one step to predict the next, give two steps to predic the third, give three steps to predict the fourth.

The models above are suited to this approach.

Keep in mind that **very short inputs may be useless** and may make your model worse. (Try to imagine how many steps would be reasonably enough for you to start predicting the next ones)

Preprocess your data and divide it in groups:

- group with length = 4 (for instance)
- group with length = 5
- ...
- group with length = 28

You will need a manual training loop where in each epoch you feed each of these groups (you can't feed different lenghts all together).

---

Another approach is, give all steps, make the model predict a shifted sequence like:

- `inputs = original_inputs[:, :-1]` #exclude last training day
- `outputs = original_inputs[:, 1:]` #exclude first training day

For making the models above suited to this approach, you need `return_sequences=True` in every LSTM that uses the day dimension as steps (not the `inner_seq`). (The `inner_average` method will fail, and you will have to resort to the `daily_minutes` approach with `return_sequences=True` and another `Permute((2,1,3))` right after.

Shapes would be:

- branch1 : `(m, d, 360, units1)`
- branch2 : `(m, d, 360, few_units)` - needs to adjust the `Reshape` for this

  - The reshapes using 1 timestep will be unnecessary, the `days` dimension will replace the 1.
  - You may need to use `Lambda` layers to reshape considering the batch size and variable number of days (if details are needed, please tell me)

## Training and predicting

(Sorry for not having the time for detailing it now)

You then can follow the approaches mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46901371/how-to-deal-with-multi-step-time-series-forecasting-in-multivariate-lstm-in-kera/46934799#46934799) and [here too, more complete with a few links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50235563/2097240). (Take care with the output shapes, though, in your question, we are always keeping the time step dimension, even though it may be 1)

The important points are:

- If you opt for `stateful=False`:

  - this means easy training with `fit` (as long as you didn't use the "different lengths" approach);
  - this also means you will need to build a new model with `stateful=True`, copy the weights of the trained model;
  - then you do the manual step by step prediction
- If you opt for `stateful=True` from the beginning:

  - this necessarily means manual training loop (using `train_on_batch` for instance);
  - this necessarily means you will need `model.reset_states()` whenever you are going to present a batch whose sequences are not sequels of the last batch (every batch if your batches contain whole sequences).
  - don't need to build a new model to manually predict, but manual prediction remains the same

Comment: Wow, this is impressive. Thank you so much for the detailed answer. I am still reading and trying to understand the things you have mentioned. Please give me like two days to fully unserstand the things you have mentioned. If there is anything unclear I will ask it in comments. Thank you so much once again. This is very helpful Honestly, I was stuck in this question for about a month now. So, thank you so much for helping me :)

Comment: Thank you very much once again for the detailed answer. I think, I understand most of the parts of your answer now. However, now I have the difficulty in implementing them. It would be really great if you could show me how to do the training with `model case 1`. I can follow the same code to do it using `model case 2`. More specifically, I am not sure how to do this in keras `You will need a manual training loop where in each epoch you feed each of these groups (you can't feed different lenghts all together).`. I look forward to hearing from you. Thank you very much.

Comment: What time of time windows did you choose? The second link in my answer shows how to train.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment. I went through the links and wrote the code today. However, I have few questions on my code. Due to the limited space in comments, I included my code in the following google document: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1v6kA2Y8fzTPMVl-JvZgAe-UZHKze2jcLE3HNK8bEzhk/edit?usp=sharing I hae mentioned the questions I have in the same document. Please kindly let me know if there are any issues in the code. The document is editable. So, please correct if there any issues in the code. I look forward to hearing from you. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please kindly let me know if you do not have the access to the document :)

Comment: Only when I'm at home, sorry. :(

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment. That is totally fine. Please let me know your thoughts when you are at home :)

Comment: I am very excited to know your feedback on the code that I wrote from your `time shifted` method. The code is in: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1v6kA2Y8fzTPMVl-JvZgAe-UZHKze2jcLE3HNK8bEzhk/edit#heading=h.autrvvehmtj9 Please kindly let me know your thoughts on this. I look forward to hearing from you. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed feedback. I found it very useful. I corrected my code based on your feedback. I have few doubts that I would like to verify from you before I use it in the experiment. My edited code is in: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1v6kA2Y8fzTPMVl-JvZgAe-UZHKze2jcLE3HNK8bEzhk/edit#heading=h.autrvvehmtj9 Please kindly let me know if I have done things correct this time. Thank you very much for your support. Looking forward to hearing from you :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback. I am currently using your code in my dataset. Thank you very much :)

Comment: I was able to run half of the code. However, I got error in the middle of the code as `"RuntimeError: You must compile a model before training/testing. Use model.compile(optimizer, loss)."`. I have mentioned the place I got the error in the document: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1v6kA2Y8fzTPMVl-JvZgAe-UZHKze2jcLE3HNK8bEzhk/edit#heading=h.p1v7iulqho0l I was thinking whether I need to mention something like this `model.fit(X, y, epochs=50, verbose=0)`. However, since we are using batches I am not sure if it is correct. Please kindly let me know your thoughts on this :)

Comment: Oh, I get the point now. Do you mean something like this `model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])`? What is the `loss`, `optimizer` and `metrics` that you would recomment to my problem? I look forward to hearing from you. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Loss is probably "mse" if you used a "linear" activation at the end, I like the "adam" optimizer, it's usually good. I'm not sure we have good metrics except for "mae". You might have used sigmoid (from 0 to 1 and try "binary_crossentropy").

Comment: Thanks a lot. :) I am so sorry that I get one more error in the line `model.train_on_batch(batch_x, batch_y)`. The error is `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (15, 25, 300)`. The dimensions of my my real dataset got little changed. Now I have details of 2865 machines on 26 days that are 300 length long (i.e. `input_data.shape = (2865, 26, 300)`). Therefore, I set the batch size to `15`.  Please kindly let me know your thoughts on how to resolve this error. Looking forward to hearing from you. Thank you very much.

Comment: The output shape of your model must match the shape of the "target" (batch_y). Your model is currently outputting 2D data `(None, something)`, you made a model that loses the time dimension somewhere. See the model summary

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment. Yes you are correct, it seems like the model output (batchsize, day_27_prediction) (i.e. `(15, 300)`). I have mentioned the `model.summary()` results in the edit section of my question. However since we are dealing with batches isn't is correct? I am not so sure what is the problem due to my limited knowledge in deep learning. I am so sorry. However, if you have any idea to resolve this issue please kindly let me know. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Don't you want to ask a new question? That's a basic "target shape" different from "model output shape" issue. Show your model, show the error, etc. All you need is that your model's output shape matches your `batch_y` shape.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are going to a good direction, to increase the time steps in each day, you will need to add a pad in your data, this example can help you: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/imdb_lstm.py#L46.

However, I would also try another approachs, like fix the number of time steps, for example, 3 days, 4, 5... And then, evaluating your train, you can choose how many time steps is the best for your model.

Maybe your initial approach increasing the number of days will be better, but in this type of problem, find the best number of time steps in a LSTM is very important.